# require using AMD pattern gives error for jQuery UI events

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, requirejs, jasmine, amd

In my code test.js is dependent on jquery-ui which does not uses require AMD pattern and test.spec.js dependent on jquery-ui, test.js which uses AMD pattern. Can we load dependency of jquery-ui in test.js dynamically when running test.spec.js.

```
require.config({

    baseUrl: '/demo',

    paths: {
        'jquery': '../library/jquery-1.11.1',
        'jquery-ui': '../library/jquery-ui-1.11.4'
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: 'jQuery'
        },
        'jquery-ui': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'library/src/js/test': {
            deps: ['library/jquery-1.11.1', 'library/jquery-ui-1.11.4', '../js/collapse'],
            exports: 'Test'
        }
    },
    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

In test.js "draggable" of jquery-ui draggable event is written. after evaluating `$('#panelId').draggable({revert: true});`
 got error

> "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   '$('#panelId').draggable({revert: true})')"

How to load jquery-ui for test.js in require.config. As i am using this to run my jasmine test cases.
In real environment it is working as expected, but in jasmine test case not able to find jquery-ui event.
test.js is not using require.js, but test.spec.js uses the require AMD pattern.

in test.spec.js code after executing this got error of jquery-ui draggable  undefined

```
define(['jquery-ui','library/src/js/test'], function ($) {

});
```

I am able to access jquery ui in test.spec.js using $, not in test.js where jquery-ui event is written as test.js does not uses AMD require pattern. Don't know what is missing. any help will be appriciated... :)

Comment: Can u create jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: @venkat7668  in library/src/js/test i am using jquery-ui reference which does not uses require.js, while loading dependecy it execute library/src/js/test file and throws jquery-ui event undefined error.

Comment: So you mean that  `library/src/js/test.js` is not an AMD module?

Comment: @tonyjmnz Yes it is not using AMD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this updated require js config

Use "library/src/js/test" to load your test

```
require.config({

    baseUrl: '/demo',

    paths: {

        'jquery': '../library/jquery-1.11.1', // assuming this is a correct path
        'jquery-ui': '../library/jquery-ui-1.11.4'  // assuming this is a correct path
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: 'jQuery'
        },
        'jquery-ui': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'library/src/js/test': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'jquery-ui', '../js/collapse'], // changes done here
            exports: 'Test'
        }
    },
    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

Comment: i had tried this approach but test.js itself has dependency on jquery-ui, whereas i am getting jquery-ui reference in test.spec.js. test.js is not using AMD pattern/ require.

Comment: So if test.spec.js is not using require then how are you loading the required dependecies for your test.spec.js?

Comment: test.spec.js uses require but test.js is not using require.

Comment: so you are loading first test.js and then test.spec.js?

Comment: Is it possible for you to load the test.js using require js?

Comment: no i can't use require.js in test.js, i need to load 1st test.js function on which i had written test cases in test.spec.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86959/discussion-between-kushal-and-rahul-rajput).

Comment: currently i am getting jquery-ui reference in test.spec.js but not in test.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `jquery-ui` instead of the path to your file.

```
shim:{
     'jquery': {
            exports: 'jQuery'
          },
     'jquery-ui': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
}

define(['jquery-ui','library/src/js/test'], function ($, test) {
    //code goes here
});
```

Comment: I tried this approach not working mate... It gives error Error: Script error for: jquery-ui
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror